# How can I access cookie information inside a component rendered on _app.js in next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my next.js app, I stored a hashed token from an OAuth2 provider using cookies. After the user completes the process, they are logged in and the cookie is stored.

This log in button is in a `Navbar` react component I've made, and is being rendered on every page via `_app.js`. It includes a conditional rendering system so if the cookie is valid it will not render the log in system. Before I realized that I wasn't going to be able to do what I wanted, I was planning on using `getServerSideProps()` to do this. However, I realized this is not going to work. How can I go about doing this?

Here's my `Navbar.jsx` file:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import axios from 'axios';
import { doOAuthWork } from '../lib/handleDiscordOAuth2';

function returnLoginInfor(parsed) {

}

const Nav = ({ parsed }) => (
  <div className="navbar z-10 top-0 fixed shadow-lg bg-neutral text-neutral-content inset-x-0 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-lg">
    <div className="px-2 mx-2 navbar-start">
      <span className="text-lg font-bold">
        Status+
      </span>
    </div>
    <div className="hidden px-2 mx-2 navbar-center lg:flex">
      <div className="flex items-stretch">
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Home
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Status
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Dashboard
          </Link>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="navbar-end">
      {doOAuthWork()}

    </div>

  </div>
);
export default Nav;
```

(full disclaimer, never finished the function yet)

And here is my `_app.js`:

```js
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
import Nav from '../components/Nav';

import discordOAuth2 from '../lib/handleDiscordOAuth2';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
      {' '}
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>Next and MDX Blog</title>

        </Head>
        <div className="container-fluid mx-auto w-full scrollhost" id="container4">

          <Nav> </Nav>
          <main className="scrollhost" id="container2">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </main>
        </div>
      </>

    </CookiesProvider>

  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

How should I go about doing this? What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance. :}

(I am a bit of a noob here at react/next so bear with me!)

EDIT: Still having this issue here, I've re-read documentation and not sure what the proper way to go about doing this is.

Comment: Since you're using `react-cookie`, why not use the [`useCookies`](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie#usecookiesdependencies) hook directly in `Nav` to retrieve the cookie data?

Answer (score 0):

**You can call an api in _appjs itself, and pass it to your components**.
The api called in _app.js will be called everytime.

> Below is the sample code.

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
import Nav from '../components/Nav';

import discordOAuth2 from '../lib/handleDiscordOAuth2';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, apiData }) {
  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
      {' '}
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>Next and MDX Blog</title>

        </Head>
        <div className="container-fluid mx-auto w-full scrollhost" id="container4">

          <Nav apiData={apiData}> </Nav>
          <main className="scrollhost" id="container2">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </main>
        </div>
      </>

    </CookiesProvider>

  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const apiData = await getApiData();
  return { apiData };
};
export default MyApp
```

Comment: I prefer @juliomalves's solution here, `getInitialProps` is going to disable optimization and I didn't want that in this case.

Comment: Are you doing getServerSideprops or staticProps ?

Comment: Not really needed in this case anymore however `getServerSideprops` is what I would have used if it works in _app.js (before my other solution.)